# How to create Laravel Storage link to root after remove public folder

Tags: laravel, storage

I removed public folder Now I want to create storage link to root folder name `upload`

filesytems.php

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/upload',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

When I use `php artisan Storage:link` it's create a public folder. But I don't want this. 
I also try

`ln -s storage/app/public upload` 
But got error massage
'ln' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Nobody is there?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54495420/6038111) question and answer do what you want?